# accessing uploaded files from hosted website temp folder

Tags: php, file-upload, temp, penetration-testing

I am learning "penetration testing of web server / websites". I am testing a web server security with the following steps:

> Test 1:
>        Through inspect element tools I added new form element
>
> Test 2: 
>        I filled the form elements which were already exists and browse php file through my injected input file tag, when i submit the form,
>   it submitted and also uploaded the file (sure the uploaded file would
>   be pitched in temp folder of that website temp folder)
>
> Test 3:
>        Now I am hanged here, because I don't know how to access that php file i uploaded with Step 2?

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

For the uploaded file to be run directly from the browser would imply that the temporary folder is inside the web root which is a major security flaw that you will not find frequently.

Hopefully very few people are stupid enough to change that default configuration option to put temporary files in the web root.

Comment: great answer, it means i have only very few chances to find such kind of servers from where i can get my uploaded files?

Comment: Indeed.  Using that kind of knowledge can be useful to learn how to secure systems, but don't go around hacking other people which is illegal and immoral.

Comment: In deed this is not something hacking i want to learn but to test your webserver, you must know how you will do it? @Julie Pelletier

Comment: That's why I suggested https://www.hackthissite.org/ which is a legal way to learn hacking so that you know what you need to protect your site against.